# C#MySQL How to modify a repeated fields?

Tags: c#, mysql

When I modify a repeated field, all the repeated  are modified

```
String sql = "update Almacen set id_almacen=" + TB_ID.Text +
             ",nom_almacen='" + TB_NOM.Text + 
             "',pais='" + TB_PAIS.Text + 
             "',municipi='" + TB_MUNICIPI.Text + 
             "' where id_almacen=" + st.Id_alamcen + 
             " AND nom_almacen='"+st.Nom_almacen+"';";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not providing a unique row column such as the row ID then SQL simply does not know which row you're wanting to change and modifies all of them.

Think of it this way, if you have a bucket of green apples and I tell you to throw away the green apple. If you're going to do exactly what I said you'd throw all of them away. However if they were numbered and I asked you to throw away the green apple numbered 37 then you'd just throw the single apple away.